# How to hide your linksys webpanel from your public ip

Tags: networking, ip

I have Apache Web Server setup on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and it's open to the internet through port forwarding. I also have it connected to a domain, but I have to do:8888 at the end of the domain each time if I don't it infinity loads unless I put the:8888. How do I make it so I don't have to type the:8888 at the end each time?

Model Number for my router is EA9500

Comment: Having your router's config page public-facing is not default behavior. There should be a setting in your router's control panel that disables that "feature". It's impossible for us to help you without the exact model number of your router.

Comment: Where would i find my model number

Comment: Likely on a sticker on the router, or on the front of it.

Comment: OK i found the model is EA9500

Comment: Are you testing from inside your network? That may not work. Also keep in mind that only what you set up will work. Unless you forward port 80 (to wherever), port 80 won't be available.

Comment: I port forwarded to port 80 as the inner port and 8888 as the outer port. Also, I tested it from my phone's data and found that when you go to my domain it infinitely loads instead of bringing me to the router control panel it still only works when I add the :8888 it works

Comment: First, note that you usually cannot test or use a port forward from inside your network. that requires a tech called Hairpinning in your router, and most home routers don't support it. That is likely where your hang is coming from. Second, you won't be able to get rid of the :8888 on the internal network, unless you host the service on 80 or 443. you can use it from outside your network, but inside your network you need to go to server:8888 rather than pubIP:80.

Comment: Frank Thomas, Please post you comment as an answer so i can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few things going on here, and they are combining into somthing that appears confusing (but is actually rather simple once we unpack it).

First, your Router has two interfaces, the WAN and the LAN. On the WAN side, TCP\80 is mapped to a port forward rule, but on the LAN interface, TCP\80 is used for the Router Management website.

So the first thing you need to understand is that a NAT router won't let you hit both interfaces from any position on the network (LAN or WAN). On a standard home router, when a packet addressed to your router is received, it will be handled by the nearest interface, and since you have different services on each interface, the result will be different if you are inside the LAN, or on the WAN side. This is why when you connect to the public IP or DNS name from Inside the LAN, you get the Router Management page. It does Not mean however that people hitting tcp\80 from the WAN can see your router page.

Even if you did not have the same port configured on both interfaces, you would not be able to connect to the public IP/DNS name from inside the LAN, without a technology called NAT [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (also called Reflective NAT). This feature is common on enterprise grade routers, but uncommon on home/SOHO grade devices.

Now all this isn't really a problem, because there is no need to hit the public IP from within the LAN. There isn't a NAT between your LAN devices, so your clients can just access the server directly at :8888.

Finally, the reason you have to add :8888 on the end, is that browsers will only go to port 80 or port 443 by default, so you have to add the port number to the url if you want to use another port. if you don't like having it on 8888, and the server doesn't already have a service on port 80, you can reconfigure your service to run on 80, and change your port forwarding rule to point to :80 instead. then your LAN clients would only need to enter the server IP/Name.

Hope that helps